# Create PDF file based on HTML template with image, image doesn't show

Tags: ios, swift

I use an HTML template to create a PDF file.

In my HTML template, I have an image. The source of this image is a local URL on my device:

`<img src="/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9BB15532-804F-43C6-BF39-23271EB9340E/MyApp.app/icon.png" style="width:100%; max-width:100px; background-color: #cdcdcd">`

The result is an empty image with a grey background.

Here is my code to create the PDF:

```
    private func exportHTMLContentToPDF(HTMLContent: String, forDay day: Date) -> String {
        let pdfRenderer = UIPrintPageRenderer()

        let printFormatter = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: HTMLContent)    
        pdfRenderer.addPrintFormatter(printFormatter, startingAtPageAt: 0)

        let docDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
        let path = "\(docDirectory)/export_\(day.toString(dateFormat: "dd.MM.yyyy")!).pdf"

        let pdfData = drawPDFUsingPrintPageRenderer(pdfRenderer)
        pdfData?.write(toFile: path, atomically: true)

        return path
    }
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Your img src tag does have a valid url.  It should look something like:

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9BB15532-804F-43C6-BF39-23271EB9340E/MyApp.app/icon.png" style="width:100%; max-width:100px; background-color: #cdcdcd">
```

Replace the "www.example.com" part with your specific web site domain.

Comment: The URL I gave is a local URL of my iphone

Comment: Oh, got ya.  But I don't know that will embed the image like you are trying to do.  The receiver will not be able to reach that endpoint.

Comment: Hmm... true. Actually I use an HTML template to create a PDF file but the image doesn't show up in the PDF. I guess I'll delete this question and ask another one with the complete question. Thanks anyway